Spectrum of $T(\cdots , x_{-2}, x_{-1}, (x_{0}), x_{1}, x_{2},\cdots )=(\cdots ,x_{-2}, x_{-1}, 4x_{0}, (3x_{-1}), x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2},\cdots )$
Find spectrum, eigenvalues and eigenvectors of operator $T:\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})\to \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$,  defined by
$$T(\cdots , x_{-2}, x_{-1}, (x_{0}), x_{1}, x_{2},\cdots )=(\cdots ,x_{-2}, x_{-1}, 4x_{0}, (3x_{-1}), x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2},\cdots )$$
where element in parenthesis is in zero place of series of coordinates.
Can anyone help me if it is wrong or right!
My attempt,
$$(T−\lambda I)(x)=(\cdots , x_{-1}-\lambda x_{-2},4x_{0}-\lambda x_{-1}, (3x_{-1}-\lambda x_{0}), x_{0}-\lambda x_{1}, \cdots )=y$$.
When $y = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda ^2 = 12$ so $\sigma_p(T)=\{-2\sqrt{3}, 2\sqrt{3}\}$ and they are eigenvalues,
else $$x_n = \frac{x_0+\sum_{k=1}^{n}-\lambda^{k-1}y_k}{\lambda^n}$$ for $n\ge1$ and $$x_n = \frac{x_{-1}+\sum_{k=2}^{-n}-\lambda^{-2n+k-2}y_{-k}}{\lambda^{-n-1}}$$ for $n \le -2$. So spectrum is $\sigma(T)= \{\left| \lambda \right|\le 1\}\cup \{-2\sqrt{3}, 2\sqrt{3}\}$. But I got confusion in calculating eigenvectors.

Where did you get stuck with the eigenvectors?

Are they must be $(\cdots , 1, 1, (0), \cdots )$ and $(\cdots , 0, (1),1, 1,  \cdots )$?
